# How to build this style page like this using latex

Tags: xetex

I need to write A command reference like this, does there anyone know how to build a page like the picture ?

[image: H]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I would use the `tabularx` environment, or its breakable-over pages version, `xltabular` and the lines from `booktabs`.

Comment: Do you have source code that needs to be documented (if so which language) in that case I would start to look at code documentation packages and see what they can do for you.

Comment: I just want to build “two  Column”  style ，maybe use “table”

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion using the `paracol` package for a twocolumn layout with synchronized columns, the `booktabs` and `tabularx` package for the textwidth wide table, the `enumitem` package for a customized `description` environment and an custom command for the small headers in the left column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%% Smaller margins, no parindent and a small vertical white space between paragraphs %%%%%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}

%%%%% For a two column layout with synchronized columns, left column takes up 25% of the horizontal space %%%%%
\usepackage{paracol}
\columnratio{0.25}

%%%%% For tables as wide as the textwidth and horizontal lnes with a decent spacing %%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%%%%% For the small "headers" in the left column %%%%%
\newcommand{\myheader}[1]{\bigskip%
                          \begin{leftcolumn*}%
                            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X@{}}%
                              \toprule%
                              \textbf{#1}%
                            \end{tabularx}%
                          \end{leftcolumn*}%
                          \switchcolumn}

%%%%% For the customized description environment %%%%%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=0.5cm,labelindent=0.5cm}

%%%%% For the dummy text. Do not use in real document %%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}[\section*{alias}]
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \lipsum[4]
    \begin{description}\itshape
      \item[word] Here is the description text
      \item[other word] Here is the other description
    \end{description}
  \end{rightcolumn}

  \myheader{Syntax Description}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\itshape}lX@{}}
      \toprule
      text & longer description text that can also use up more than one line\\
      \midrule
      more text & another description\\
      \midrule
      third text & last description in this table\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

  \myheader{Defaults}
    \lipsum[4]


\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer solved my problem perfectly.